# Wanted to show some success messgae in react app after successfull registration using toast method in axios post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-toastify

Actually i wanted to show some successfull message after hitting signup button using axios post method  so that i have used toastify module in react but only catch option is working then is not working ...i am stuck here i dont know what to do...so please help me to sort this...
here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {toast} from 'react-toastify'; 
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';  
toast.configure();
function Regform(){
const [user,setInput]=useState({
    ecode:"",email:"",phone:"",password:"",cpassword:""
})
function Handle(event){
const {name,value}=event.target;
setInput(prevInput=>{
    return {
        ...prevInput,
        [name]:value
    }
})
}
function postData(event){
event.preventDefault();

const newNote={
    ecode:user.ecode,
    email:user.email,
    phone:user.phone,
    password:user.password,
    cpassword:user.cpassword
}

axios.post('http://localhost:4000/create',newNote)
.then( response => {
    toast('Successfull registration ');
})
.catch( error => {
    toast('Invalid registration ') ;
})

}
return (
    <>

    <form method="POST">
        <fieldset>
                <legend><i>Registration Form</i></legend>
        <input type="text" placeholder="employee code" name="ecode" value = 
{user.ecode} onChange={Handle} autoComplete="off"/><br/>
        <input type="email" placeholder="email" name="email" value ={user.email} 
onChange={Handle} autoComplete="off"/><br/>
        <input type="number" placeholder="phone" name="phone" value ={user.phone} 
onChange={Handle} autoComplete="off" /><br/>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" value = 
{user.password} onChange={Handle}  autoComplete="off"/><br/>
        <input type="password" placeholder="confirm password" name="cpassword" value 
={user.cpassword} onChange={Handle} autoComplete="off" /><br/>
        <button onClick={postData}>Register</button>
        </fieldset>
  
    </form>
    </>
)
}

export default Regform;
```

and here is my backend code for the same and for database i have used cloud mongo db

```
const mongoose =require('mongoose');
const express=require('express');
const cors=require('cors');
const app=express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://raushan: 
<password>@cluster0.ofx36.mongodb.net/nodeDB",{
useNewUrlParser:true,
useUnifiedTopology:true,
useCreateIndex:true
}).then( () => {
    console.log('Connected to database ')
})
.catch( (err) => {
    console.error(`Error connecting to the database. 
\n${err}`);
})

app.use("/",require("./routes/noder"));


app.listen(4000,()=>{
console.log('sever is running at a port no 4000')
})
```

Comment: well, your axios.post() is not successfull

Comment: No after hitting signup button axios.post() is working and actually data is inserted but no successful message promt but if a made some mistakes then catch is working and this message "invalid registration" prompt. that means only catch is working but then is not working

Comment: console.log the status from axios response -> not sure it's 200

Comment: i have  add console.log(response.status ) if promise is fulfilled but again nothing is printing and when i  made some mistakes and add console.log(error.status) it is printing "undefined" that means then is not working but catch is working with some mistakes while data is inserting if promise is fulfilled...;)

Comment: Can you show the code you have used in your backend to create the user?

Comment: yeah sure i have attached my backend code you can go through it